# AngularJS Filter Hide Item If It Exists In Another Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have two arrays:

```
$scope.arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
$scope.arr2 = [2, 3, 4];
```

I'm trying to:

- ng-repeat through `arr1`
- Use a custom filter to only show items from `arr1` that aren't in `arr2`
- The output should be `1`

Here's my view:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in arr1 | matcher">
    {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.filter('matcher', function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.arr1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.arr2.length; j++) {
      if ($scope.arr1[i] != $scope.arr2[j])  {
        return $scope.arr1[i];
      }
    }
  }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
  $scope.arr2 = [2, 3, 4];
});
```

Here's my Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Pd3QwMMNfmL62vvdD1kW?p=preview

Any idea how to get this custom filter working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will never get access `$scope` inside the angular filter in any way, you should pass them as parameter inside your filter and then access them inside your filter function. For making it more cleaner you could take use of `.filter` & `.indexOf` inside your filter.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in arr1 | matcher: arr2">
        {{item}}
      </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.filter('matcher', function() {
  return function(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.filter(function(val) {
      return arr2.indexOf(val) === -1;
    })
  }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
  $scope.arr2 = [2, 3, 4];
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/xJppMP2gg7dLPN6pahmZ?p=preview)

Comment: @Ryan Glad to here that it does help you...Thanks :)

Comment: Done. The 15 minute accept answer delay is really annoying. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Do you know if it's possible to make this filter an array of objects (i.e. only return `Red` and `Orange`): http://plnkr.co/edit/I6vNcceHi2TBkgxJhygc?p=preview

Comment: @Ryan It could be look something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/McgDHPm5KAEXJ4bEtWln?p=preview If you use `_` lodash.js then it could be more simpler

Comment: That looks great. I am using lodash - here's the Plunker with lodash 3.10: http://plnkr.co/edit/MuuWL4TyIIQD5nSCmPte?p=catalogue